# DataTables warning: table id=clientTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7 Failed to load

Tags: jquery, spring, datatables

I'm trying to add DataTables to my application. The data is large so I want to use the serverSide processing and I've been following this: https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables . I the repository interface I extended the DataTables repository:

```
public interface CompanyRepo extends DataTablesRepository<Company, Integer>
```

I also created the method in the Service class that fetches the data and returns a DataTables object:

```
 public DataTablesOutput<Company> findAll(DataTablesInput input) {
        return repo.findAll(input);
    }
```

And the get method in the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/listCompanies")
    public DataTablesOutput<Company> listCompanies(@Validated DataTablesInput input) {
        return companyService.findAll(input);
    }
```

The request mapping URL for the controller methods is:

```
@RequestMapping("company/employee")
```

And the method that returns the HTML template for the list to be viewed uses the ModelAndView object:

```
@GetMapping("list-clients")
    ModelAndView getAllClients() {
        return getFirstTenEntities("list-clients",
                "companies");
    }
```

And in the HTML template this I configure the DataTables like:

```
let table = $('#clientTable').DataTable({
    ajax: "/listCompanies",
    serverSide: true,
    columns: [
        { data: 'clientCode' },
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'assignments' },
        { data: 'clientType' },
        { data: 'tel' }
    ]
});
```

I get this error in my browser console, what am I doing wrong?
[image: Image of 404 error]

Comment: The 404 seems self-explanatory.   The `ajax: "{URL}",` does *not* point to your service endpoint.

Comment: @freedomn-m ok understood, how do I service the endpoint?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do [tag:spring]